# How to stop youtube video in modal window?

Tags: jquery, youtube

I have this code in my html:

```
<div class="modal-pop modal-pop1">
    <div class="modal_bg"></div>
    <div class="modal_container wrap">
        <div class="wrap_modal_container">
            <img src="img/modal_button_exit.png" alt="" class="modal_button">
            <div class="vid">
                <iframe width="100%" height="437" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/c_LxX0Sbq2k?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this whole block is set to `display: none`
then I use jQuery to show it by

```
$('.listen-example').click(function(){ 
    $('.modal-pop1').fadeIn()
})
```

and this code to close the modal window

```
$('.modal_bg, .modal_button').click(function() {
        $('.modal-pop').fadeOut();
});
```

It works fine, but after closing the modal window, youtube video still continues to play, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `iframe` a **unique id** say `'myid'` and try below code :-

```
$('.listen-example').click(function(){ 
    $('.modal-pop1').fadeIn();
    $("#myid").attr('src','//www.youtube.com/embed/c_LxX0Sbq2k?rel=0');
});

$('.modal_bg, .modal_button').click(function() {
    $('.modal-pop').fadeOut();
    $("#myid").attr('src','');
});
```